# Remove Gnome from Ubuntu Gnome after switching to Cinnamon

Tags: gnome, uninstall, cinnamon, ubuntu-gnome

I installed Cinnamon on top of Gnome in Ubuntu Gnome 13.10.  I would like to remove the unnecessary parts of gnome, primarily the settings which show as duplicates with the cinnamon ones, making it hard to distinguish which is which.  I tried removing gnome-shell, but it caused the computer not to boot to the login screen.  Even If I must keep some parts installed, how can I remove the unnecessary components of gnome?

Answer (score 1):

As the Gnome Settings panel is the application `gnome-control-center`, you can remove it by running `sudo apt-get purge gnome-control-center`. This gets rid of of the duplicated settings items it the menu.

Hint: I have no clue why, but at the first time removing the control center apt wanted to install a bunch of unity stuff and even unity8, so check what apt-get will do before typing `Y` ;)